# Clicking and hovering on a gsap-powered svg-map

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am trying to make this clickable map. When the mouse hovers on one element the other elements will fade. When it leaves things turn back as they were.

```
$('*[id^="odlare"]').hover(function(){

$(this).appendTo('#odlarkarta');
var id = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
var therest = "#odlarkarta > *:not(" + id + ")";
gsap.to(therest,{duration: 1, opacity: 0.2});
gsap.to(this,{duration: 1, scale: 1.2,  transformOrigin: "center center"});

}, function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var therest = "#odlarkarta > *:not(" + id + ")";
gsap.to(therest,{duration: 1.2, opacity:1});
gsap.to(this,{duration: 1.2, scale:1, transformOrigin: "center center"});
});
```

That works fine. When I click on an element, that element will expand and stay expanded and the hover-function will no longer be active.

```
$('*[id^="odlare"]').click(function(){

$(this).appendTo('#odlarkarta');
var id = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
var text = id + " text";
var therest = "#odlarkarta > *:not(" + id + ")";
gsap.to(therest,{duration: 1, opacity: 0.2});
gsap.to(this,{duration: 1, scale: 4,  transformOrigin: "center center"});
gsap.to(text,{duration: 1, opacity: 1});
```

Here I am lost. And when I click outside of an expanded element everything turns back to its natural state. How?

```
$('*:not(' + id + ')').click(function(){
gsap.to(therest,{duration: 1, opacity: 1});
gsap.to(this,{duration: 1, scale: 1,  transformOrigin: "center center"});
gsap.to(text,{duration: 1, opacity: 0});
});

});
```

I don't know where to start or finish, but here's where I am right now:

https://codepen.io/larshallen/pen/YzamdVM

I also would like to add one extra function eventually and that is that if I click a second time on an already clicked item, then a link will active and I will be transferred to another location.

Answer (score 0):

the css selector `:not()` on one of the click events is responsible for triggering your therest method which sets the scale back to 1.

for the hover effect I would use the 'mousemove' event listener and add a 'focused' class to 'ev.target' element and storing the currently focused element in a variable so that you can easily remove the class from it and set it on the new target element when it changes.
mousemove triggers often, so make sure not to update anything unless it needs to.

as for the last part, use the dom El dataset to store the link target element ID and pass it to the `gsap.to()` method e.g.

`<svg data-targetid="#fooplace" >`

`$('*[id^="odlare"]').click(function() { gsap.to($(this.dataset.targetid) //..`

some details needed

edit:

example of hover

```
let focused
const handleMouseMove = (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.id === focused.id)
    return // skip uneccessary updates
  else {
    focused?.classList.remove('focused')
    ev.target.classList.add('focused')
    focused = ev.target
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
```

and it's basically the same for what you want with click, just change the listener to 'click' and class to 'clicked'

Comment: Great idea with the dataset, thanks!

Can you give me an example of how to use mousemove and the focused class? I am not very experienced. Do you think I can use a class "clicked" also, would that be good?

Comment: everything is at your disposal, just remember defining those classes in css, updated my answer btw